# Function only returning first value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have a function that parses and splits out a message body into separate properties. However, when I run it I'm only getting the first value returned. Any suggestions on what I'm missing, note has to be ES5.

Expected Result:

```
{Current Update: "Investgations in progress.",
      Description: "Service Portal Unavailable",
      Impact: "Customers unable to access Service Portal",
      Incident number: "INC0012345",
      Incident start date/time: "27/07/2020 12",
      Ref: "MSG3207258_sCxJ4T6p2y21HH2w4xdS",
      Services affected: "Service 1"}
```

Actual Result:

```
{Incident number: "INC0012345"}
```

Input msgBody:

```js
{"Incident number":" INC0012345\\n\\nIncident start date/time: 27/07/2020 12:56:59 AEST\\n\\nServices affected: Service 1\\n\\nDescription: Service Portal Unavailable\\n\\nImpact: Customers unable to access Service Portal\\n\\nCurrent Update: Investgations in progress.\\n\\nRef:MSG3207258_sCxJ4T6p2y21HH2w4xdS"}
```

Script:

```js
(function execute(inputs, outputs) {
  var props = inputs.msgBody.split(/\\n+/);
  var res = {}; // =[];

  for (i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    var tmp = props[i].match(/(.*?):(.+)/);
    if (tmp) {
      if (tmp[1] && tmp[2]) {
        res[tmp[1]] = tmp[2].trim();
      }
    }
  }

  outputs.payload = JSON.stringify(res);
})(inputs, outputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit this is my first attempt at writing ES5-compatible code.  And it takes a different approach than you did.  But I believe it produces the desired result.

```js
var raw = { "Incident number": " INC0012345\\n\\nIncident start date/time: 27/07/2020 12:56:59 AEST\\n\\nServices affected: Service 1\\n\\nDescription: Service Portal Unavailable\\n\\nImpact: Customers unable to access Service Portal\\n\\nCurrent Update: Investgations in progress.\\n\\nRef:MSG3207258_sCxJ4T6p2y21HH2w4xdS" };
var medium = "Incident number:" + raw["Incident number"];
var done = medium.split("\\n\\n");
var wellDone = done.map(function (elem) {
  var key = elem.split(":")[0];
  var colonIndex = elem.indexOf(":");
  var value = elem.slice(colonIndex + 1).replace(/ /, '');
  return new Array(key, value);
});
var served = new Object();

for (var i = 0; i < wellDone.length; i++) {
  served[wellDone[i][0]] = wellDone[i][1];
}

console.log(served);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach I think it's es5-compatible it's not much different from your code i just added `filter`

```js
inputs = {
  "Incident number":
    " INC0012345\\n\\nIncident start date/time: 27/07/2020 12:56:59 AEST\\n\\nServices affected: Service 1\\n\\nDescription: Service Portal Unavailable\\n\\nImpact: Customers unable to access Service Portal\\n\\nCurrent Update: Investgations in progress.\\n\\nRef:MSG3207258_sCxJ4T6p2y21HH2w4xdS",
};

function execute(inputs) {
  var props = ("Incident number :" + inputs["Incident number"]).split(/(\\n)/g);
  var prop = props.filter((n) => n!='\\n' && n!="");
  var res = {};
  for (i = 0; i < prop.length; i++) {
var tmp = prop[i].split(/\s?:(?=[^0-9])\s?/);
    {
      res[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(execute(inputs));
```